# Dispose a student without memory leak

Tags: c++, oop

I have a program Student . OOP Student , I wrote constructor but I don't know how to destructor a Student because I use string instead of char* for the student name

Here is my class . Construction function has run. Can you help me write Destructor ? Because Student name data type is string so I can't use `delete[]this->m_Sname.`

```
class Student {
private:
    string m_Sname;        //Student Name
    double m_SMathPoint;   //Student Math Point
    double m_SLiPoint;     //Student Literature Point
public:
    Student(string, double, double);  //Initialize a student with name, math, literature points
    Student(string);                  //Initialize a student with name, math = literature = 0.
    Student(const Student& s);        //Initialize a student from another student
    ~Student();                       //Depose a student without memory leak
    void printStudent();
};
```

Comment: Just remove `~Student();` :) The default destructor will do the right thing.

Comment: Unless you are using pointers and allocating memory using "new" or "malloc", you do not have to "delete" or "free" the memory. Here you are just using an object of the std::string class. So when the object is destroyed, the default destructor should deallocate the memory.

Comment: This illustrates one of the advantages of using `std::string` over `char*` -- the memory management is taken care of for you. You don't need to worry about this at all!

Comment: You can lose the copy constructor also ('rule of zero').

Comment: What book did you read about C++? I recommend [*Programming: Principles and practice using C++*](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321992789/samplepages/9780321992789.pdf)

Comment: The other reason why you should not write a destructor when not needed is that the compiler may be able to optimize the code better seeing that what will be called is the compiler default destructor instead of your empty destructor.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you help me write Destructor ?

Yes, here you go:

The best destructor is the destructor you don't write, i.e. you let the compiler generate it for you. This should be the default. You should extremely rarely -
close to never manually manage resources in C++.

You should read on the [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

> ### Rule of zero
>
> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or
> copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership
> (which follows from the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)). Other
> classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or
> copy/move assignment operators.
>
> This rule also appears in the C++ Core Guidelines as [C.20: If you can avoid defining default operations, do](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-zero).

In some cases (think of [GUI toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) such as [FLTK](https://fltk.org/)) you would need to write an explicit destructor, but in most cases you don't.

Answer (score 5):

std::string will automatically free the memory it consumes when a Student exits scope or is destroyed due to the mechanisms of RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). Basically, when a variable's life-cycle ends, either through it leaving scope implicitly or being destroyed some other way, its destructor will be called, and then the destructors for all of its members will be called (unless those members are dumb-pointers or references to the data, then they have to be manually freed). Therefore, the destructor for m_Sname will be called implicitly when a student variable is destroyed.

As cigien stated in a comment on your post, just remove your definition for the destructor, or, alternatively if you wish to be explicit you may say something like `~Student() = default;`, which will accomplish the same thing.

In case I haven't been clear, here is some code:

```
void f()
{
    Student john("John", 0.75, 0.75); // Constructor
    Student *betty = new Student("Betty", 0.8, 0.7);
    ...
    // john is about to leave the scope
    // the scope being the end of function 'f'
    // john's destructor will automatically be called.
    // betty's destructor will not be called unless manually destroyed
    //     by doing 'delete betty;'
    // 
    // ~Student() for 'john' is here - the string stored inside 'john' will also
    //     be freed when john is freed.
    // ~Student() for 'betty' is NOT here. The pointer would have to be freed 
    //     or a memory leak will occur.
}
```